# Change color of span upon click

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/SmileySteven/pen/pdBYdv?editors=1111

```
function test(){
  var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= span.length ;i++){
    span.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor === '#ffffff'? this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
         : this.style.backgroundColor="#000000";                          
   })
 }
}
test();
```

Hello guys, I am trying to change the background color of my spans upon click but it does not seem to work - care to guide me as to what I am doing wrong?  I have set all span to background color of `#ffffff`

Answer (score 2):

> **1 -** JavaScript always garbing ***White backgrounds*** From HTML as **null** 
>   for Printing purpose .

so in case the background you trying to match is white 
**then replace** :

`this.style.backgroundColor === '#ffffff' ? ..... etc ;`

with this :

```
this.style.backgroundColor === "" ? this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
     : this.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
```

otherways if the background your trying to match is ***Not*** white 
 
then you can use the condition normal *`element === " color code here "`*

> **2 -** finally as others mention add the loop in front of your span callback like this :

```
span[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
span.addEventListener('click', function(){
```

You are setting the event to whole collection of spans. You should set to the individual element

```
span[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOvamO?editors=1111

Comment: Hi thanks alot, but im confused.  So logically should ALL the spans then be set to black since I set "the whole collection?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(){
  var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  
  span.forEach((item)=>{
    item.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      let styles = getComputedStyle(item);
      styles.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' ? item.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow' : item.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    });
  });
}
test();
```

```css
.def.def2{
  background-color:orange
}

div#ya{
  background-color:purple
}

span{
  
  background-color:#ffffff
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i1">   </input>
<input type="text" id="i2">   </input>
<input type="number" id="i3">   </input>
<button id="btn">  sad </button>
<div> Div1  </div>

<div class="def def2"> div2 </div>
<div id="ya" class="def def2 def3 omg"> div2 </div>
<p> sad </p>

<span > test </span><span> test </span><span> test </span>
```

I recommend to use `forEach` with `querySelectorAll()`.

And, if you want to get the value of `background-color`, you should better use `getComputedStyle()`.

But, `getComputedStyle().backgroundColor` always return `rgb()`, so you have to use `rgb()`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the above answer, I would also recommend running test on document ready.

```
$( document ).ready(test);
```

Updated codepen with fix: https://codepen.io/TheRodeo/pen/pdBYVJ